# building a dynamic list of named arguments for {fmt}

Tags: c++, fmt

I am using the [{fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) and need to build a dynamic list of arguments. Basically, I have a format string like per the documentation page

```
fmt::print("Hello, {name}", fmt::arg("name", "test"), ...);
```

but the arguments list (including how many arguments there are) is known only at runtime. I've looked at `fmt::ArgList` which takes a list of `fmt::Arg` instances. But the named arguments are an internal class `fmt::internal::NamedArg` which I cannot see how to pass to the list.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without delving to deep into the code it dosn't seem to be possible. Either use string streams or [the fmt libraries write API](http://fmtlib.net/3.0.0/#write-api)? Or if the data you want to print is the same, then perhaps use something as described in [this issue regarding `std::initializer_list`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/181), it should be easy to replace with e.g. a `std::vector`. Using the solution presented in the issue, you could use e.g. a vector of `std::any` (or `boost::any`). if you don't have a uniform type for all items you want to print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution using fmtlib internals. The following code formats a string from a string-string dictionary using fmtlib. Special handling had to be included to handle arg-counts >= 16, as fmtlib uses an optimization for smaller argument lists.

```
// helper only:
inline void set_type(fmt::ULongLong& result, uint32_t index, fmt::internal::Arg::Type t)
{
    unsigned shift = index * 4;
    uint64_t mask = 0xf;
    result |= static_cast<uint64_t>(t) << shift;
}

// input: 
//     pattern = fmt::format string
//     vars = dictionary of string/string arguments
// output:
//     formatted string
std::string dformat(const std::string& pattern, const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>& vars)
{
    // this is a vector of "named arguments" - straightforward enough.
    std::vector<fmt::internal::NamedArg<char>> av;

    // fmtlib uses an optimization that stores the types of the first 16 arguments as 
    // bitmask-encoded 64-bit integer. 
    fmt::ULongLong types = 0;

    // we need to build the named-arguments vector. 
    // we cannot resize it to the required size (even though we know it - we have the
    // dictionary), because NamedArg has no default constructor.
    uint32_t index = 0;
    for (const auto& item : vars)
    {
        av.emplace_back(fmt::internal::NamedArg<char>(item.first, item.second));

        // we need to pack the first 16 arguments - see above
        if (index < fmt::ArgList::MAX_PACKED_ARGS)
        {
            set_type(types, index, fmt::internal::Arg::NAMED_ARG);
        }
        ++index;
    }

    // and this is a bit tricky: depending on the number of arguments we use two mutually
    // incompatible vectors to create an arglist. It has everything to do with the speed
    // (and memory) optimization above, even though the code looks nearly identical.
    if (index >= fmt::ArgList::MAX_PACKED_ARGS)
    {
        std::vector<fmt::internal::Arg> avdata;

        // note the additional terminating Arg::NONE
        avdata.resize(vars.size() + 1);
        index = 0;
        for (const auto& item : av)
        {
            avdata[index].type = fmt::internal::Arg::NAMED_ARG;
            avdata[index].pointer = &av[index];
            ++index;
        }
        return fmt::format(pattern, fmt::ArgList(types, &avdata[0]));
    }
    else
    {
        std::vector<fmt::internal::Value> avdata;

        // no need for terminating Arg::NONE, because ARG_NONE is the last encoded type 
        avdata.resize(vars.size());
        index = 0;
        for (const auto& item : av)
        {
            avdata[index].pointer = &av[index];
            ++index;
        }
        return fmt::format(pattern, fmt::ArgList(types, &avdata[0]));
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> vars;
vars["FIRSTNAME"] = "Foo";
vars["LASTNAME"] = "Bar";

std::string result = dformat("Hello {FIRSTNAME} {LASTNAME}, how are you doing", vars);
```

Answer (score 7):

{fmt} has inbuilt support for dynamic argument list starting with 7.0.0.

Named dynamic args:

```
fmt::dynamic_format_arg_store<fmt::format_context> store;
store.push_back(fmt::arg("const", "pi"));
store.push_back(fmt::arg("val", 3.14f));

std::string result = fmt::vformat("{const} = {val}", store);
// result is "pi = 3.14"
```

Unnamed dynamic args:

```
fmt::dynamic_format_arg_store<fmt::format_context> store;
store.push_back("answer to everything");
store.push_back(42);

std::string result = fmt::vformat("{} is {}", store);
// result is "answer to everything is 42"
```

Comment: Remember to include the "fmt/args.h" library, don't be like me and get a compilation error.

Comment: If I allow users to specify the format string, can I somehow specify that unnamed (positional) args should be ignored (since their order is an implementation detail)? Or should I manually escape positional arguments?